# Oracle 11g: Confounding constraint

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a referential constraint that will not enable, even though the referenced values are indeed in the referenced table.  I have closely looked over the spelling in the constraint script and in both tables.

When I try to enable the constraint, the error returned is 'parent key not found'.. I physically compared the data, and the values needed are indeed in the referenced table.

The referenced column is set as Primary Key and that is enabled.

The involved process concerns a data load/transfer from another schema/database via a dblink.

In the source tables for the data transfer, there is a similar constraint that is indeed enabled.

Can't really post the data due to data sensitivity, was just hoping I could get some ideas of further things to check.

Any ideas or suggestions appreciated.

Code for constraint:

```
  ALTER TABLE SR2.LOG ADD (
  CONSTRAINT FF1 
   FOREIGN KEY (NOTCH_ID) 
   REFERENCES SR2.NOTCH (ID)
    DISABLE NOVALIDATE);
```

Comment: Do users keep inserting data on any of parent or child tables while you validate the FK? Is this being done on a production database?

Comment: The source table is production, but the referenced values can be seen in the referenced table.

Comment: Perhaps the order in which a user process inserts data might be the cause. Things like inserting on the child table first. Just an idea though. Did you try the EXCEPTIONS clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an Oracle built-in solution for that. 
You could use the EXCEPTIONS clause of the ALTER TABLE:

```
  -- parent table
  create table t1 (col1 number primary key);

  insert into t1 values (1);
  insert into t1 values (2);
  insert into t1 values (3);
  commit;

  -- child table
  create table t2 (col1 number);

  insert into t2 values (1);
  insert into t2 values (2);
  insert into t2 values (3);
  insert into t2 values (4); -- bad data
  commit;

  -- You create a table for the exceptions
  create table excepts  (row_id rowid,
                         owner varchar2(30),
                         table_name varchar2(30),
                         constraint varchar2(30));

  -- you still get error
  alter table t2 add constraint f2 foreign key (col1) references t1
  exceptions into excepts ;

  -- but bad data will be here
  -- please notice its 'ROW_ID' from the second table
  select t2.*
  from  t2,
        excepts 
  where t2.rowid = excepts.row_id;
```

Comment: You could still use it in the ENABLE VALIDATE statement:  
alter table t2 enable validate constraint f2 
exceptions into excepts ;

Comment: +1 There is always something new to learn. Is there a way to prevent the error during `alter table`? Do you know ther RDBMS which support a similar syntax?

Comment: @Beryllium The error is for you to know something went wrong. I just work with Oracle, I have no idea if other RDBMS has this feature.